# How do I map a small object graph using Entity Framework Code First 4.1?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have a very small object graph that I'm using:

```
public struct Address
{
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    etc...
}

public class User
{
    public Address HomeAddress { get; set; }
    public Address WorkAddress { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    etc...
}
```

Using Entity Framework 4.1, how would I map this structure to one table so that they're mapped to columns like:

```
HomeAddressLine1
HomeAddressLine2
WorkAddressLine1
WorkAddressLine2
FirstName
LastName
etc...
```

Comment: Make the `struct` a `class` and try to map it as a complex type. If you have a problem after trying that, post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF doesn't support structures. You must use class for your Address and map it as complex type:

```
public class Address
{
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Address HomeAddress { get; set; }
    public Address WorkAddress { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}


public class Context : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                    .Property(u => u.HomeAddress.AddressLine1)
                    .ColumnName("HomeAddressLine1");
        // Use the same pattern for all columns of HomeAddress and WorkAddress
    }
}
```

Comment: ...plus `modelBuilder.ComplexType<Address>();`, right? Or does EF recognize `Address` as complex type automatically because of the dotted path in `Property(...)`?

Comment: I expect that it should recognize it because `Address` doesn't have key and it is used in `Property` mapping but if it doesn't your assumption will fix it.

Comment: It works even without any mapping, just tested it. The missing key in `Address` seems to be enough to make it a complex type.

Comment: Yes it is but it will use different column names, won't it?

Comment: Yes, some composed default naming with underscores: `HomeAddress_AddressLine1` etc.

Comment: I didn't know that a `ComplexTypeDiscoveryConvention` even exists. I'd thought that EF will complain about missing key but the exception is: "*When Code First discovers a class definition where a primary key cannot be inferred, and no primary key is registered through data annotations or the fluent API, then the type is automatically registered as a complex type. Complex type detection also requires that the type does not have properties that reference entity types and is not referenced from a collection property on another type.*" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh161541%28v=vs.103%29